# What are the practical applications of the lowest common ancestor algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, tree, least-common-ancestor

I was having a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540622/lowest-common-ancestor-of-binary-treenot-binary-search-tree) and then reading about [Tarjan's least common ancestors algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm). I never came across any applications of LCA algorithms before.

Where are such LCA algorithms commonly used?

Comment: Spatial data structure trees in scientific computing, suffix trees for strings in computational biology, etc. Forgot the details, sorry, but it's definitely useful.

Answer (score 6):

In compilers, the LCA of two basic blocks is a place you can put a computation so it is available to both. This might be useful for eliminating common subexpressions, or inserting phi-node for SSA conversion. These algorithms are well evolved and highly optimized, though, so the LCA itself may be hard to see, e.g., [SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) and [PRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_redundancy_elimination)

Answer (score 5):

Don't know where it is used, but I have a couple ideas where it might get used:

- computer graphics: often 3D sceneries get split into cubes which form a tree structure. If you have an object which is contained in two such cubes a LCA algorithm gives you the smallest containing larger cube.
- analysis of gens in order to find the relationships between species and their lowest common ancestor
- merge algorithms of version control systems

Comment: thanks!  version control -> three way merge: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(revision_control)#Three-way_merge

Comment: It is also useful for certain kinds of string processing when looking for root words for different suffixes.

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote a  blog post about how I had to implement my own algorithm for this problem (extended to a set of nodes with an arbitrary length) for a taxonomy tree in the context of metagenomics:

http://blog.bio4j.com/2012/02/finding-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-set-of-ncbi-taxonomy-nodes-with-bio4j/

Cheers,

Pablo